# PHP function runs twice

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am rather new to PHP, so I write my code by finding code snippets and trying to piece them together.

I have code that makes a screenshot by URL, and then uploads that URL to the WordPress media library. The image URL from the WordPress media file is then placed in a custom field.

The following code works, except that the code saves the image twice.

```
function wpscreen($post_id) {
$test = "https://www.google.com/";
$testurl = 'https://s.wordpress.com/mshots/v1/' . $test . '?w=' . '211' . '&h=' . '172' . '.jpg';
$desc    = get_the_title($post_id);
$new_image_url = media_sideload_image($testurl, $post_ID, $desc, $src = 'src' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpscreen' );
```

I assume it is because I call the variable `$new_image_url` a second time, but I am not sure how to get the URL in my custom field otherwise.

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT** I made the code simpler,  but the image still gets uploaded twice.

**EDIT 2 (Solution)**
Apparently `Save_post` runs twice (sometimes/always?). By adding the following snippet around my code, it worked fine.

```
if( ! ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id) || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) ) {

}
```

Comment: 2 questions: Can't you just do `$test . '?w=211&h=172.jpg'`? Also not sure why you have `$src = 'src'`. Shouldn't that be just `'src'`?

Comment: thank you for the reply.  Both of your points are correct (first one, the numbers are a variable in the real code though)

I think i found a solution to my problem, aparantly 'save_post" runs twice when you save. so adding a check to see if its an autosave/revision it seems to only save once now